# Required an expert suggestion in TSQL

Tags: sql, windows, algorithm, architecture

I have a scenarios where Table A has reference to Table B , Table B has a reference on Table C column ...etc.

To implement an update task in my project I ought to implement it in two phase logic
i.e. delete the row first and add the latest again.

But unfortunately , when I try to delete a row in table A it has reference which in turn has reference to other table and so on. Hence my logic of delete and add does not work in a proper way all the time. Even if it is deleted and added again , the sequence at which it is being added is last i.e. as a new record. Hence I am losing all the earlier references track in the same order as old one.

Hence I would like to delete a row from a table without effecting the references i.e. for time being it should allow to ignore reference , once i added it again i.e update record then i need to re-enforce/enable back the reference.

Is it possible to do in such a way ? or there any other logic works in similar fashion or replace the original intention ? could anyone please provide your expertise advice on this ?

How general logic of windows service pack works ? can any one elaborate on that? or share some info or doc or blog regarding the same?

Thank you so much.
Regards,
Shyam

Comment: You could try adding a bit column that indicates a record in your top-level table is enabled or disabled (1 or 0), essentially. Then maybe have some scheduled job run after hours which could then clean out any such records along with any child records of theirs in the other tables down the line. For that you'd need to start from the bottom up, begin at the lowest-level table and work your way up, to avoid running into the foreign key constraints.

Comment: "To implement an update task in my project I ought to implement it in two phase logic i.e. delete the row first and add the latest again"  In general, that sounds like a bad idea.  If it really is a good idea, and you want people to give you answers that support this, then you should probably add more details to your post to explain why you are doing this, and convince others that it is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a bad practice, I would rethink your design. It doesn't let you delete the parent record because there are child records. That is what the database ii supposed to and to try to circumvent it is a 100% guarantee of bad data.

If what you are trying to accomplish is to move the child records to a new parent, that can be done but you add the new record first and then make updates. It is best if you have some field to be able to define what old record it used to be associated with or a mapping table to use to make many changes. Then you would need to run updates for every child table. This kind of thing shoudl be a one time change, not a regular practice. It certainly shoudl virtually never happen from the application and shoudl only be done by a qualified databse developer.

If what you are trying to accomplish is to inactivate the parent so it can no longer be used for some purposes(such as creating new orders) and leave the details for reporting (wouldn't want to lose the finacials for old orders), then you should put an active flag on the table and use that to filter records instead. Often this means creating a view of only active records and pointing the code to the view insted of directly to the table.